# I am stuck on this one question where I have to find the coefficient of x^2. It is non-calculator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What is the coefficient of $x^2$ in 
$$
\left(4-x^2\right)\left[\left(1+2x+3x^2\right)^6-\left(1+4x^3\right)^5\right]
$$

A calculator cannot be used.

Comment: please check the equation

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Note: a calculator would not help even if it were allowed. This is algebra. Use what you know about multiplying polynomials.

Comment: polynomial expansion is tedious but you need to know how. See what you can do with the end points of $(X+1)^6$ and you may get a feel for this problem. In the mean time, I think I worked out $312x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No amount of looking at this solution will produce enough facility for you to do these problems yourself.  You should make yourself understand the *idea* of this answer -- that you can ignore anything with degree $>2$ -- and then try to do the problem using that idea.

Since we only want the $x^2$ coefficient, we don't care about any power of $x$ greater than $2$ at any point in the computation.  So from
$$  \left(4-x^2\right)\left[\left(1+2x+3x^2\right)^6-\left(1+4x^3\right)\right]  $$
we can immediately restrict to
$$  \left(4-x^2\right)\left[\left(1+2x+3x^2\right)^6-\left(1\right)\right]  $$
Then \begin{align*}
(1+2x+3x^2)^6 &= ((1+2x+3x^2)^2)^3  \\
    &= \left( (1+2x+3x^2) \cdot 1 + (1+2x+3x^2)\cdot 2x + {} \right.  \\
    &\qquad \left. (1+2x+3x^2) \cdot 3x^2) \right)^3  \\
    &= \left((1+2x+3x^2) + {} \right. \\
    &\qquad (1 + 2x + \text{[don't care]})\cdot 2x + {} \\
    &\qquad \left. (1 + \text{[don't care]})\cdot 3x^2 \right)^3  \\
    &= (1+4x+10x^2)^3  \\
    &= (1+4x+10x^2) \cdot (1+4x+10x^2) \cdot (1+4x+10x^2)  \\
    &= (1 + 4x + 4x + 10x^2 + 16 x^2 + 10x^2 + \text{[don't care]}) \cdot (1+4x+10x^2)  \\
    &= (1 + 8x + 36 x^2 + \text{[don't care]}) \cdot (1+4x+10x^2)  \\
    &= 1 + 4x + 8x + 36 x^2 + 32 x^2 + 10x^2 + \text{[don't care]}  \\
    &= 1 + 12 x + 78 x^2 + \text{[don't care]}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
There are many ways to keep track of the bookkeeping in the above.  It can even be done entirely mentally, with practice.  Now we can reduce our interest to
$$  \left(4-x^2\right)\left[12 x + 78 x^2 \right]  = 48x + 312 x^2 + \text{[don't care]}  $$
and we are done.

Comment: Beautiful. I just carried out your method and completely understood how this can be done! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

**HINT**

Let $\left\{x^2\right\} A(x)$ denote the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expression $A(x)$. Then,
$$
\begin{split}
\left\{x^2\right\} \left(4-x^2\right)[f(x)-g(x)]
 &= 4\left\{x^2\right\}[f(x)-g(x)] - \left\{x^0\right\}[f(x)-g(x)] \\
\end{split}
$$
So what are the coefficients of $x^0$ and $x^2$ in your expressions?